# Error saying "cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Tags: python, algorithm

```
class Tests():

    def genes():
        t=int(input())
        for i in range(t):
            num = int(input())
            numbers = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
            return num, numbers

    def solve(num, numbers):
        while num>0:  
            profit = 0
            while numbers:

                pos = numbers.index(max(numbers))
                for i in range(pos):
                    profit += (max(numbers)-numbers[i])
                numbers = numbers[pos+1::]
                num -= 1
            return profit


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        for num, numbers in genes():
            print('#{0} {1}'.format(i+1, solve(num, numbers)))
```

I don't know why "for num, numbers in genes():" causes an error and how to fix this

Comment: what is `i` in last line  `print('#{0} {1}'.format(i+1, solve(num, numbers)))`

Comment: Your class methods should include `self`, e.g. `def genes(self):` ... It appears that your `if __name__=="__main__"` block is inside the class definition so the method appears to work. But other code doing `t = Tests();t.genes()` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

`genes()` is returning the first `tuple` of `num, numbers` and nothing else. I suspect you intended it to generate all pairings, so you could actually iterate over multiple results, unpacking each as you go to `num` and `numbers` in the caller. To do so, change `return` to `yield` to make it a generator function:

```
def genes():
    t=int(input())
    for i in range(t):
        num = int(input())
        numbers = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
        yield num, numbers  # Only change
```

The problem was caused because you effectively said:

```
for num, numbers in (genes_num, genes_numbers):
```

causing it to try to unpack the single `num` from `genes` into `num` and `numbers`.

You may want to check your `solve` function as well; the `while num > 0:` line will only ever be evaluated once, because you unconditionally `return` at the bottom of said loop. It's unclear why this should be a `while` loop at all, given `numbers` will be exhausted in the inner loop, and without it, any subsequent runs of the outer loop will unconditionally set `profit` to `0`.

I'll also note that defining methods on a class that aren't `@staticmethod`s and don't take `self` is an issue; you're getting away with it because you run your "main" code in the scope of the class definition (so the class isn't actually involved), but it's distinctly odd. You probably don't need a class at all.

Comment: Great answer but you may want to fix the problem with no `self` in the method while you're here.

Comment: @tdelaney: Yeah, it's not actually breaking their code (because the "main" code runs within the scope of the class definition, so it's calling plain functions, not methods of a class or instance), and fixing it piecemeal won't work (just adding `@staticmethod` or `self` with no other changes would actually *create* a problem, as `@staticmethod` isn't callable unless accessed through the descriptor protocol, and `self` won't exist when the class hasn't been defined and an instance instantiated), so I didn't want to dwell on it, but yes, it's another problem.

Comment: Easiest fix: Remove the line `class Tests():` and reduce the indentation of everything by 4 spaces :-)

Comment: @alexis: Yar. That's where "You probably don't need a class at all." comes in. Didn't want to bother with detailed solutions to a problem when I'm not sure what their constraints are, and there are many valid solutions.